# Sound not initializing at startup

Tags: audio

I've got a RPi I am using for some retro-gaming with RetroPie and Dosbox installed.  If I start X and attempt to run a game through Dosbox, I do not get sound.  However, if I first start RetroPie and start a game (e.g. from the NES emulator) I do get sound from the emulator and I can then exit, start X and hear sound from dosbox.  Other programs (e.g. Mathematica) also require these steps in order to work and even emulationstation itself does not emit its bells and whistles until I've returned from one of the emulators.

lsmod reports that snd_bcm2835 is installed and making sure that audio is going to the right place with `sudo amixer cset numid=3 2` doesn't change anything.  I've exhausted my troubleshooting ideas at this point.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do something like play an MP3, then start X, does that work?

Comment: @Fred I get no sound if I try to play an mp3 or wav; however as with X if I start one of the emulators in EmulationStation, which is apparently doing something to initialize my sound, I can get sound playing properly.

Comment: This is just a silly thought I had, but have you checked to make sure the volume is turned up before you start the emulator?

Comment: @Fred perhaps not totally silly - as I'm sure there's something obvious going on here.  But to answer your question, yes, I have made sure that the volume is set.  It seems as if the emulator is initializing sound in some manner that isn't being done at boot.  I have tried a fresh installation on another SD card (just Raspian) and I can get sound to work find there, so I think I've narrowed it down to a configuration error on my emulationstation build.

Comment: That is strange, but good news. It means it's solvable in some fashion, even if it's just reconfiguring a new card. Maybe start by checking if they're using the same firmware though? Then comparing installed package versions...